# How do you add app wide CSS files using the Angular CLI?

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli

I want to add some shard styling to my Angular 2 app, things like fonts and color schemes that will be used every where.  In the past I have always done this by adding a tag like this to my index page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework.css" />
```

This doesn't work with whatever the CLI is using to serve the app.  I tried manually adding the css files to the dist folder after building, but that doesn't seem to work either.

I also tried adding the css in the `anugular-cli-build.js` folder like this

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'css/*.css'
    ]
  });
};
```

It still doesn't seem to build the files in the `css` folder out when I tell it to build.

The style sheet in question is meant to be the base line styles for the entire app and not something I want to have to include in the styleUrl tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the vendorNpmFiles configuration is for telling the cli build which node_modules to copy into the dist directory.

I was able to just create a 'resources' directory in my src directory, put my app-wide css file in there, and it was copied over to the dist build without any further configuration.

```
src
|- app
|  |
|
|- css
|  |
|  |- framework.css
|
|- index.html
```

If you're trying to include a framework like bootstrap, then yeah, you can use the vendorNpmFiles configuration to copy it from your node_modules:

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'bootstrap/dist/**/*',
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Then your reference in your index.html would be:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I was putting the css folder at the same level as the src folder instead of at the app level. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

In the latest ng cli just adding required styles and scripts like below in ".angular-cli.json" will expose it in bundle automatically

```
"apps":{
 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/ng2f-bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
  "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ],
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go!

Comment: added the custom .css from node_modules package to the list of styles to be used in "styles" in my ".angular-cli.json" and when i build the app i see the styles.bundle.js being generated.

How ever when i run the App the Styles are missing. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

Do i need to add any references in the index.html page ?

Thanks

Comment: Anyone on the diff on adding it to angular.json instead (worked for me)? Using the CLI, but didn't find an angular-cli.json. That's in Angular 6.

Answer (score 3):

Since the files you're referring to (i.e. `[framework-x].css`) are static you can utilize the `public` directory to copy files directly to the `dist` folder without any additional configuration.

based upon your inclusion of:

```
src
|-- public
|   |-- framework-x.css
```

your file will be moved to the dist directory like this:

```
dist
|-- framework-x.css
```

So you can reference it in index.html directly.

Comment: didn't work for VS2022. I've to create the folder "public" is not coming with the default template. In any case returns 404.