# How to use ng-bootstrap with AngularJS 2 (using angular-cli v1b15)?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have been trying to use ng-bootstrap in my Angular 2 project following the documentation on the ng-bootstrap official site.

What I have done are as follow:

1. `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.4`
2. Navigate to the root /bootstrap directory and run `npm install` to install local dependencies listed in package.json.
3. Navigate to the root project again and run `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

After that, I import in the module as follows:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PageModule } from "./page/page.module";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        NgbModule,
        PageModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

However, I am still unable to use the bootstrap styles, such as pull-left, in my project.

For information, I am using angular-cli v1.0.0-beta.15 with webpack.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Verify the index.html file includes the .css file of bootstrap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you add app wide CSS files using the Angular CLI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465022/how-do-you-add-app-wide-css-files-using-the-angular-cli)

Comment: @galvan thx. I have figured out

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource my case is different, I am using webpack instead of systemjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out. It is actually stated in angular-cli github page as well, in the section of [Global Libray Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation), as follow:

Some javascript libraries need to be added to the global scope, and loaded as if 
they were in a script tag. We can do this using the `apps[0].scripts` and 
`apps[0].styles` properties of `angular-cli.json`.

As an example, to use [Boostrap 4](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/) this is 
what you need to do:

First install Bootstrap from `npm`:

```
$ npm install bootstrap@next
```

Then add the needed script files to to `apps[0].scripts`.

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
],
```

Finally add the Bootstrap CSS to the `apps[0].styles` array:

```
"styles": [
  "styles.css",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
],
```

Restart `ng serve` if you're running it, and Bootstrap 4 should be working on 
your app.

Comment: scripts can be "../node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js" from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started at least as of today (11/30/2016)

Comment: you do NOT need jquery.js, tether.js nor bootstrap.js when using ng-bootstrap - the whole point of the ng-bottstrap library is to _replace_ those scripts with native Angular 2 code.

Answer (score 4):

On your imports for the decorator you need to call ngBootstrap like this

```
NgbModule.forRoot()
```

Example AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

// Add This
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
 AppComponent,
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes), 
  // Add This
  NgbModule.forRoot()
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```