# Popover from ng-bootstrap in Angular

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

I want to put a bootstrap popover to my button but it won't open when I click it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ngbPopover="content" popoverTitle="title" placement="right">Click Me</button>
```

The following lines are excerpt from my `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        NgbModule,
        ...
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: It works for me. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qq8t9l).

Comment: Make sure you've included bootstrap styles in your angular.json. Also note that you should include NgbModule in the module that declares your component

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that the ng-bootstrap version doesn't match my angular version.

Answer (score 0):

> Check out this [page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) to get information about which version of
>   bootstrap & angular is compatible with which version of ng-bootstrap.
>   For example, **I'm using ng-bootstrap version 1.x.x in my angular5
>   project built with bootstrap CSS 4**

**Currently, ng bootstrap can only be used with angular 5+ but here is a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643845/how-to-use-ng-bootstrap-with-angularjs-2-using-angular-cli-v1b15) where some folks have tried using ng-bootstrap with angular 2.**